# How can I create a Universal Windows Application using TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

Visual Studio 2015 does not have a project template for Universal Windows Applications in TypeScript. I would like to know how to get started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015.1, this works out-of-the-box. In 2015.2 and 2015.3 however, you have to work around a TypeScript installation bug. See second part for a how-to.

With the Universal SDK installed, go to `New Project -> JavaScript -> Windows -> Blank App (Universal Windows)`. Simply change `main.js` to `main.ts` and you're set.

---

If you're running Visual Studio 2015.2 or 2015.3, you need to tweak your TypeScript install first. Shout-out to [@minestarks on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8950#issuecomment-231170405):

> I assume you're running in an English locale here, otherwise I don't think the workaround is applicable.
>
> Close VS.
>   In an administrator command prompt:
>
> `cd %ProgramFiles(x86)%\msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio\v14.0\typescript
>   mkdir en
>   copy *.xaml en
>   copy TypeScript.Tasks.dll en\TypeScript.Tasks.resources.dll`
>
> Now open your UWP project again, the TS files should be visible and building when you build your project.