# How can I break inside a TypeScript UWP app in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, win-universal-app, uwp

Minimal reproduction (in VS 15 Preview 2):

1. Create a new project using the "JavaScript -> Windows -> Universal -> Blank App (Universal Windows)" template.
2. Rename `main.js` to `main.ts`.
3. Add a `tsconfig.json` file to your project (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493863/how-can-i-create-a-universal-windows-application-using-typescript-in-visual-stud) for why).
4. Enter the following code in `main.ts`:
   `declare var foo: any;
   foo();`
5. Go to "Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings" and check "JavaScript Runtime Exceptions".
6. Click the green "Run on Local Machine" button.

An error message appears:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app [...]. The wwahost.exe process started, but the activation request failed with error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application. This usually indicates that the target application's process aborted. More information may be available in the Debug pane of the Output window (Debug->Window->Output)'.

Expected behavior: the IDE should break on `foo();`.

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild the project and try again.

Comment: I just tried clean + rebuild, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work-around for VS 2015 Update 3 (s/o to [@minestarks on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8950#issuecomment-231170405)):

> I assume you're running in an English locale here, otherwise I don't think the workaround is applicable.
>
> Close VS.
>   In an administrator command prompt:
>
> ```
> cd %ProgramFiles(x86)%\msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio\v14.0\typescript
> mkdir en
> copy *.xaml en
> copy TypeScript.Tasks.dll en\TypeScript.Tasks.resources.dll
> ```
>
> Now open your UWP project again, the TS files should be visible and building when you build your project.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure [Typescript for VS2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) is installed, and try with other codes. I tried with following codes:

```
function buildName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
let result3 = buildName("Bob", "Adams");
```

Make sure your "tsconfig" is correct:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": 
    {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
    "main.ts"
  ]
}
```

Make sure your `main.js` and `main.js.map` files are generated correctly(show all files in solution explorer to see these two files):

main.js:

```
function buildName(firstName, lastName) {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
var result3 = buildName("Bob", "Adams");
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

main.js.map:

```
{"version":3,"file":"main.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["main.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAC,mBAAmB,SAAiB,EAAE,QAAgB;IACnD,MAAM,CAAC,SAAS,GAAG,GAAG,GAAG,QAAQ,CAAC;AACtC,CAAC;AAED,IAAI,OAAO,GAAG,SAAS,CAAC,KAAK,EAAE,OAAO,CAAC,CAAC"}
```

And here is my basic demo project:[TypescriptDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/TypeScriptDemo)

Comment: I tried your steps, and I tried the demo project, and in both cases I can't put breakpoints in the `.ts` files.

Comment: [Latest version is confirmed broken.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8950#issuecomment-229214106)